# JDBC ResultSet closed in Java after several iterations

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, resultset, sqlexception

I am having a problem with a `ResultSet` being closed. What confuses me is that it works for a portion of the data and then closes. At first I thought it might be because of connection timeout but that doesn't seem the case.

This portion of the program pertains to comparing an `.xlsx` workbook to an already present `SQL` database and for lack of a better term merges/updates it.

First, in my `CompareDatabase` class I am calling a search function that searches an `SQLite` database for a specific string every 6 iterations.

```
int columnCount = 6;
dataPoint = dataPoint.replaceAll("Detail", "");
String[] temp = dataPoint.trim().split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));
for (String tempDataPoint : temp) {
    if ( columnCount == 6) {
         System.out.println(search(tempDataPoint, connection));
    }
    columnCount = 0;
    } else {
         columnCount++;
    }
}
```

This search function (also in the `CompareDatabase` class is then supposed to search for the value and return a String (was originally a Boolean but I wanted to see the output).

```
private String search (String searchValue, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement pStatement = null;
    pStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM lotdatabase where (Vehicle) = (?)");
    pStatement.setString(1, searchValue);

    try (ResultSet resultSet = pStatement.executeQuery()){
        return resultSet.getString(1);
    }finally {
        close(pStatement);
    }
}
```

At the end you can see that the `PreparedStatement` is closed. The `ResultSet` should also be closed automatically (I read somewhere) but JDBC could possibly be being unreliable.

The `Connection` however is still open as it will be searching some 200+ strings and opening and closing that many times did not seem like a good idea.

These functions are called by my `main` class here:
One is commented out since it will error out because of primary key violation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SQLDatabase sqlDatabase = new SQLDatabase();
    //sqlDatabase.convertToSQL("Database1.xlsx");
    sqlDatabase.compare("Database2.xlsx");
}
```

I have a suspicion that I am going about a bunch of this wrong (on the aspect of managing connections an such) and I would appreciate a reference to where I can learn to do it properly.

Also, being that `PreparedStatement` can only handle one `ResultSet` I don't see that being my issue since I close it every iteration in the `for` loop.

If more code or explanation is required please let me know and I will do my best to assist.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: what does `close(pStatement)` do?

Comment: It calls the close function which in of itself is basically just `pStatement.close()` but it just makes it look a little prettier since I close many statements and all.

Comment: You are using `try-with-resources` so you shouldn't `close` yourself.

Comment: True. Before though; even without the `try-with-resources` it would still close when I attempted to use `if` logic on the result set. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Without knowing what your exceptions stacktrace looks like I can only guess. Consider using a DBCP for the connection and *close* it each time.

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit more Googling and sleeping on it here is what worked for me.

The search function in `compareDatabase` changed to this:

```
private Boolean search (String searchValue, Connection connection) {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM lotdatabase where " +
                "(Vehicle) = (?)");
        ps.setString(1, searchValue);

        ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();

        //The following if statement checks if the ResultSet is empty.
        if (!resultSet.next()){
            resultSet.close();
            ps.close();
            return false;
        }else{
            resultSet.close();
            ps.close();
            return true;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

And in the other function within `compareDatabase` I call the `search` function like this:

```
if (search(tempDataPoint, connection)) {
      System.out.println("MATCH FOUND: " + tempDataPoint);
}else {
      System.out.println("NOT FOUND: " + tempDataPoint);
}
```

This allows me to check the `ResultSet` and also be sure that it is closed.